# How to make debug on formulas that involve Lambda and helper functions in Excel

Tags: excel, lambda

Hello I apologize for this kind of question, but it is very difficult for me to logically understand and fix long formulas in Excel using lambda and helper functions.

I personally learned excel the little I know, always using f9.

In this way I repaired or corrected formulas that returned either an error or a wrong result.

Can you please help me with some suggestions from your experience to make it easier for me to debug formulas that involve lambda and helper functions?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Post few of your sample data, show your desired output. Also post your faulty formula so that we can correct it.

Comment: Harun24hr Thank you for your comment but I don't have something specific, I only want to know how you replace f9 in the lambda? how do I check to see what is behind the formula?

Comment: Seach for Excel add-ins

Comment: There is no way for now to debug, as far I know also using the `Excel` Add-in which is available it doesn't perform the same job like the `Excel` in-built feature `Evaluate` does. Usually we need to break down the formula in parts/steps to use within `LAMBDA()` @Florin Mihail

Comment: Sorry I should say it does help but it is not like the one we use `F9` or `Evaluate` feature of `Excel` -- here you can download, **[LAMBDA()-FAST_EXCEL](https://www.decisionmodels.com/FastExcellambdaexplorer.htm?)**

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thank you I will download
Now i see. That  excel add in can be very helpful.
Thank you

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya can you please post your comment as an answer so I can vote for him?
Thank you

Comment: Sorry, you can post this as your own answer, as it doesn't completely resolve the question. But i have faced this problem in initial days when started to follow and learn `LAMBDA()` from experts here, i opted for the addin, it does help to know about the matrix calculations but i was not able to get to the use of evaluation feature of excel. So i left out my research.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya ok thank you

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya what also helps from what I have searched on the internet and you probably already know from your experience is to check the result from each variable using let but if a variable represents a combination of 5,10 functions there is no chance of seeing what each of those functions returns separately.

Comment: Watch `Excel Is Fun` that might help you. Thanks!